# Automatically rename fasta files with the ID of the first sequence in each file

Tags: bash, sed, rename, file-rename, fasta

I have multiple fasta files with single sequence in the same directory. I want to rename each fasta file with the header of the single sequence present in the fasta file. When i run my code , i obtain "Substitution pattern not terminated at (user-supplied code)"

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /home/maryem/files/;
do 
  if [ ! -f $i ]; then 
     echo "skipping $i"; 
  else 
     newname=`head -1 $i | sed 's/^\s*\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'`; 
     [ -n "$newname" ] ; 
      mv -i $i $newname.fasta || echo "error at: $i"; 
  fi; 
done | rename s/ // *.fasta
```

fasta file:

```
>NC_013361.1 Escherichia coli O26:H11 str. 11368 DNA, complete genome
AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAATGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTCTCTGACAGCAGCTTCTGAACTG
GTTACCTGCCGTGAGTAAATTAAAATTTTATTGACTTAGGTCACTAAATACTTTAACCAATATAGGCATAGCGCACAGAC
AGATAAAAATTACAGAGTACACAACATCCATGAAACGCATTAGCACCACCATTATCACCACCATCACCATTACCACAGGT
```

I'm not sure if there is another way to rename each file with the ID in the header ??

Comment: You have `[ -n "$newname" ]` for no apparent reason.  Just putting that out there.  Also, it's recommended that you use `$()` instead of backticks.  (They can be nested.)

Comment: The `sed` command doesn't seem to work because you're not matching `>` at the beginning of the line. You're also not matching the `_` and `.` which seem to be part of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the ID is the first "word" of the file, you can run the following in the directory containing the fasta files.

```
for f in *.fasta; do d="$(head -1 "$f" | awk '{print $1}').fasta"; if [ ! -f "$d" ]; then mv "$f" "$d"; else echo "File '$d' already exists! Skiped '$f'"; fi; done
```

Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13161