# Rename file using fasta header

Tags: awk, sed, grep, fasta

I have multiple fasta files downloaded from NCBI and want to rename them with some part of the header:

Example of the header: `>KY705281.1 Streptococcus phage P7955, complete genome`
Example of filename: `KY705281.fasta`

The idea is to get rid of `'KY705281.1'` and `'complete genome'` so that only Streptococcus phage P7955 remain

For example, one input file will be:

```
>KY705281.1 Streptococcus phage P7955, complete genome
AGAAAGAAAAGACGGCTCATTTGTGGGTTGTCTTTTTTTGATTAAGTAATGAAGGAGGTGGATGTATTGG GCTAAATCAACGACAAAAACGATTTGCAGACGAATATTTGATATCTGGTGTCGCTTACAATGCAGCTATC AAAGCTGGGTATTCTGAGAAATACGCTAGAGCAAGAAGTCATACCTTGTTGGAAAATGTCGGCAT
```

It wlil be renamed to `KY705281.fasta` with content:

```
>Streptococcus phage P7955 
AGAAAGAAAAGACGGCTCATTTGTGGGTTGTCTTTTTTTGATTAAGTAATGAAGGAGGTGGATGTATTGG GCTAAATCAACGACAAAAACGATTTGCAGACGAATATTTGATATCTGGTGTCGCTTACAATGCAGCTATC AAAGCTGGGTATTCTGAGAAATACGCTAGAGCAAGAAGTCATACCTTGTTGGAAAATGTCGGCAT
```

I'm a newbie with Linux but somehow with some Google search, I know that this could be done easily with some awk/sed/grep commands.
Any advice would be grateful

Comment: Not clear, please do mention samples of input and expected output clearly in your post with code tags.

Comment: So would it be correct if you renamed the files to whatever is between the first space and the first comma on the first line?

Comment: Yes, change the header too and get the same name as the file. I think rename with the files whatever is between the first space and the first comma will do it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 for example '>KY705281.1 Streptococcus phage P7955, complete genome
AGAAAGAAAAGACGGCTCATTTGTGGGTTGTCTTTTTTTGATTAAGTAATGAAGGAGGTGGATGTATTGG
GCTAAATCAACGACAAAAACGATTTGCAGACGAATATTTGATATCTGGTGTCGCTTACAATGCAGCTATC
AAAGCTGGGTATTCTGAGAAATACGCTAGAGCAAGAAGTCATACCTTGTTGGAAAATGTCGGCAT' as input and '>Streptococcus phage P7955
AGAAAGAAAAGACGGCTCATTTGTGGGTTGTCTTTTTTTGATTAAGTAATGAAGGAGGTGGATGTATTGG
GCTAAATCAACGACAAAAACGATTTGCAGACGAATATTTGATATCTGGTGTCGCTTACAATGCAGCTATC
AAAGCTGGGTATTCTGAGAAATACGCTAGAGCAAGAAGTCATACCTTGTTGGAAAATGTCGGCAT' as output expected

Comment: @FiestaJ  It's better for you to put this description in the question and format it better. I think file contents like these is better to put under `{}` code block formatting.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078687/automatically-rename-fasta-files-with-the-id-of-the-first-sequence-in-each-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{match($1, "^>([^.]+)[^ ]+ (.*)", oFv); $1= ">" oFv[2]; sub(/ *complete genome */, "", $2);}{printf $0>oFv[1] ".fasta"}' somefiles*
```

This will keep old files and write corresponding new file(s).
Also this assume that the input files only have one line like you gave.

If you want to rename old files as well as change their contents,
Given your system and bash, also I think it's GNU awk & GNU sed,
please backup your files and try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for file in somefiles*; do
    nn="$(awk -F[\>.] '{printf $2 ".fasta";exit}' "file")"
    sed -ri '1{s/^[^ ]* />/;s/, complete genome//;}' "file"
    if [ ! -f "$nn"];
    then
        mv "file" "nn"
    else
        echo "'$nn' exists, skip '$file', its content already changed." | tee _err_.log
    fi
done
```

Or as oneliner:

```
for file in somefiles*; do nn="$(awk -F[\>.] '{printf $2 ".fasta";exit}' "$file")"; sed -ri '1{s/^[^ ]* />/;s/, complete genome//;}' "$file"; if [ ! -f "$nn" ]; then mv "$file" "$nn"; else echo "'$nn' exists, skip '$file', its content already changed." | tee _err_.log; fi; done
```

Comment: Hi @Tiw , thanks for the tip but it get rid of all other lines in the files except the first one. I have ubuntu 16.04 and the version 4.3.48 of bash.

Comment: So for the bash script it give this error awk: fatal: cannot open file `file' for reading (No such file or directory).  The oneliner works better but the ">" is missing. I have to run this to correct file format: `sed -i '1s/^/>/' *.fasta`

Comment: @FiestaJ  Oh, you mean the first `>` got deleted, sorry about that.

Comment: got it, I'll work around the code to deal with almost same data